# Update a specific directory on AppFog

Tags: appfog

I try to update a specific directory on AppFog for my Node.JS application, but I don't know how does it works..

I tried to execute the following command : "af update appname --path public/admin".

But it doesn't work : "No such file or directory".

And when I update all the application, all my uploaded photos are deleted. By "uploaded photos" I mean the photos uploaded by an upload form in HTML from my application in the "public/images/photos" directory!

How can I update only the "public/admin" directory?

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.afignore` file in the root directory. There you can specify the files or directories you want to ignore while running update command.

Example:

```
# ignore run.py
run.py

# ignore dot files
.*

# ignore assets directory
assets/

# ignore static directory
static/
```

Once you are done specifying the files, run `af update appname`

You can find the documentation here : https://docs.appfog.com/getting-started/af-cli/afignore